# Garageband speed up individual region

Tags: garageband

How does one speed up an individual portion (region) of a track on garageband without altering the tempo of other tracks or regions? Altering the song tempo changes everything's tempo.

Answer (score 3):

1. Enable Flex Time in the Editor
   [image]
2. Drag from the beginning of the track so that the waveform turns white. It sometimes trims instead, but it generally works when clicking the middle of the left side.
   [image]